# createStackNavigator is causing null is not an object(evaulating '_RNGestureHandlerModule.default.direction) even if it's not used

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the newest version of react-navigation.  I've made a default react-native project version 0.60.0.  I noticed that when I add:

> import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

it immediately crashes the app and gives me the error message:

> null is not an object(evaluating
>   '_RNGestureHandlerModule.defaultDirection)

I get this error message even if I'm only importing createStackNavigator.  If comment out the import, the app works normally.

My package.json looksl like this

```
{
  "name": "awesome",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "1.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^3.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

My App.js file is the standard App file with only two extra import lines.

Comment: Did you do pod install inside your ios folder?

Comment: This is for Android.  I haven't touched iOS yet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed

```
yarn add react-navigation
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

Then update the MainActivity.java

```
package com.reactnavigation.example;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
+ import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
+ import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "Example";
  }

+  @Override
+  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
+    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
+      @Override
+      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
+       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
+      }
+    };
+  }
}
```

And after that do:

> ```
> cd android
> gradlew clean
> cd ..
> ```

Then do the usual:

> react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

You can Check install list

```
    yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens@^1.0.0-alpha.23.
```

To complete the linking on iOS, make sure you have Cocoapods installed. Then run:

```
    cd ios
    pod install
    cd ..
```

To finalize installation of `react-native-screens` for `Android`, add the following two lines to dependencies section in `android/app/build.gradle:`

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

To finalize installation of `react-native-gesture-handler` for `Android`, make the following modifications to `MainActivity.java:`

```java
    package com.reactnavigation.example;

    import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
    + import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
    + import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
    + import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

    public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

      @Override
      protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "Example";
      }

    +  @Override
    +  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    +    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
    +      @Override
    +      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
    +       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
    +      }
    +    };
    +  }
    }
```